# spark UDF result can do 'show', but can't do 'filter'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

spark `UDF` works when I do `show()`, but it gives me error when I do  `filter` on `UDF` result.

udf function

```
def chkInterPunctuation(sent) :
    for char in sent[1:-2] : 
        if char in ["\"", "'", ".", "!", "?"] :
            return True
    return False

cip = udf(chkInterPunctuation, BooleanType())
```

`show()` works

```
df_punct = dfs.withColumn("in_length", length("input")).\
withColumn("out_length", length("output")).withColumn("cip", cip(col("input")))
df_punct.show()
```

[image]

but it gives me error when I do `filter`

```
df_punct.where(col("cip") == True).show()
```

these are `filter` error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-e206ffd07f75> in <module>()
----> 1 df_punct.where(col("cip") == True).collect()

/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in collect(self)
    308         """
    309         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 310             port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    311         return list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    312 

/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    931         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    932         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 933             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    934 
    935         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    310                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    311                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 312                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    313             else:
    314                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3378.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 40 in stage 238.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 40.0 in stage 238.0 (TID 8862, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
    process()
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 92, in <lambda>
    mapper = lambda a: udf(*a)
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 70, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "<ipython-input-153-fce920dc0de2>", line 5, in chkInterPunctuation
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2513)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2513)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2513)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2532)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2512)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
    process()
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 92, in <lambda>
    mapper = lambda a: udf(*a)
  File "/home1/irteam/nmt_common/nexus/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 70, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "<ipython-input-153-fce920dc0de2>", line 5, in chkInterPunctuation
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

my googling suggest that `py4j` error usually occur when `UDF` function doesn't return proper value or it has error. but my `UDF` `function` always return true or false. in addition, spark query returns right value when I do show. it doesn't make sense for me. What can be possible cause?

Thank you for in advance

Comment: Could the error be due to some udf input being to short? Or empty?

Comment: Can you update your question with some input data?

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ' __getItem__, seems to me you just need to cast the cip column to BooleanType

Comment: Before you do the filtering of course

Comment: Without knowing for sure, I'm guessing that `show()` works the same way in pyspark as it does in regular spark (scala). In normal spark, a `show` - unlike a `collect` will _not_ force evaluation of the entire dataframe but only a small part of the data. Just enough to display a tiny fraction of the result set. I suspect that there might be a problem with input data in some row that is _not_ processed by your `show` command but will indeed be processed by your `filter(...).collect()` command. Maybe try to do a `df_punct.collect()` (no filter) instead of `df_punct.show()` to verify this?

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you don't correct for `NULL` presence. Try:

```
def chkInterPunctuation(sent) :
    if not sent: return   # In None return
    for char in sent[1:-2] : 
        if char in ["\"", "'", ".", "!", "?"] :
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by updating to spark2.4.0. (I used 2.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
df = spark.sql(
  """
  select 'gjgjgjgjgjg' as word
  union 
    select 'lalalal?ala' as word
  union 
    select 'ryryry.ryry' as word  
  """)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("words")

from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
def chkInterPunctuation(sent) :
    for char in sent[1:-2] : 
        if char in ["\"", "'", ".", "!", "?"] :
            return True
    return False

cip = udf(chkInterPunctuation, BooleanType())

udf_df = df.withColumn("cip", cip(col("word")))

udf_df.where("cip = true").show()
```

Regardless, you can do this without a udf:

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT * 
FROM   words 
WHERE  word LIKE '%.%' 
        OR word LIKE '%?%' 
""").show()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because you use `show()` after applying `where()`.
I suggest first apply filter and save it in a new variable and then do `show()`.

```
df_punct_filtered = df_punct.where(col("cip") == True)

df_punct_filtered.show()
```

**UPDATE:**
or you can use `filter()` function instead of `where()`:

```
df_punct_filtered = df_punct.filter(df_punct.cip == True)

df_punct_filtered.show()
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. but it gives me same error. In my opinion, Spark do lazy evaluation, so declare new variable doesn't change meaning.

Comment: sorry but filter are just alias for where. I have tried but it doesn't work